# Training Accuracy is getting higher, but Valid Loss and Accuracy is same every epoch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, training-data

i'm doing a transfer learning with ResNet50.
My dataset is clothes(224x224x3), and 49 category(classes) -> training data 1000 per 1 category, total 49000. And valid data 200 per 1 category, total 9800. All the data are standardized (include valid data) . So I think the data unblance and the standardization is not a problem. Detail code is below this line.
(nevermind about the variable names(ex.nasnet) , sorry)

```
from keras.applications import NASNetMobile, ResNet50, VGG19, VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, AveragePooling2D, Dropout, Input, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD

from datagenerator import DataGenerator
import numpy as np
import os

# Set Parameters and Max File Count
params = {'dim': (224,224),
          'batch_size': 64,
          'n_classes': 49,
          'n_channels': 3,
          'shuffle': True}

file_cnt = 49000
max_cnt = 58800

# Datasets

train = np.arange(file_cnt)
np.random.shuffle(train)
test = np.arange(file_cnt,max_cnt)
np.random.shuffle(test)
dataset = np.append(train,test)

# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(train, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(test, **params)

# get resnet layers and weights, add FCN
nasnet_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))    

nasnet_len = len(nasnet_model.layers)

x = nasnet_model.output
x = AveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten(name="flatten")(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(49, activation="softmax")(x)

model = Model(inputs=nasnet_model.input, outputs=predictions)

layer_num = len(model.layers)
for layer in model.layers[0:nasnet_len]:
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in model.layers[nasnet_len:]:
    layer.trainable = True

model.summary()

# training
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator, epochs = 20)

# saving
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file : 
    json_file.write(model_json)    
model.save_weights("model.h5")
```

ImageGenerator

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical, Sequence

import numpy as np
import cv2
import data

class DataGenerator(Sequence): # Sequence 에 대해서 공부하
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, batch_size=64, dim=(224,224), n_channels=3,
                 n_classes=49, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = np.load('desktop/standardized_data/input' + str(int(ID)) + '.npy')
            # Store class
            y[i] = np.load('desktop/standardized_data/output' + str(int(ID)) + '.npy')
            #tmp = self.labels[int(ID)] 
            
        return X, to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

But the valid loss and accuracy is like this.

```
Epoch 6/20
765/765 [==============================] - 812s 1s/step - loss: 0.8220 - accuracy: 0.7020 - val_loss: 6.2641 - val_accuracy: 0.0345
Epoch 7/20
765/765 [==============================] - 836s 1s/step - loss: 0.7322 - accuracy: 0.7254 - val_loss: 6.8545 - val_accuracy: 0.0394
Epoch 8/20
765/765 [==============================] - 822s 1s/step - loss: 0.6664 - accuracy: 0.7432 - val_loss: 6.6525 - val_accuracy: 0.0362
Epoch 9/20
765/765 [==============================] - 799s 1s/step - loss: 0.6098 - accuracy: 0.7597 - val_loss: 6.1669 - val_accuracy: 0.0346
Epoch 10/20
764/765 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5719 - accuracy: 0.7711
```

Why this happens to me ... TT Please help me to find a reason. ( epoch 1~5 was missing, but the valid loss and accuracy were same, and the training loss and accuracy was getting better every time. )

- Now I was trying to test with some of training datas, but the result was same... That is, I trained with training data, and tested with training data, but accuracy difference was same.

Comment: If you don't get a satisfying answer here, you might have more luck on the [DataScience SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) which is a sister website dedicated to Data science professionals and Machine Learning specialists

Comment: may be overfitting ?

Comment: Can you try shuffling data first and then do the train test split?